# Scrapy do not get setting fetch from curl scrapyd settings

Tags: curl, scrapy, settings, scrapyd

I want to send settings to the crawler by:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/ -d project=project -d spider=spider -d 
setting=request_user=2
```

Or using scrapyd python api:

```
scrapyd.schedule(project,spider,settings={'request_user':2})
```

And then from within spider:

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings=get_project_settings()
request_user=settings.get('request_user')
```

However, I always get `request_user==None`, which mean that crawler never receive setting from scrapyd schedule. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`request_user` is a spider variable, not a setting. So you can pass it to spider like this:

Scrapyd JSON API:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json -d project=project -d spider=spider -d request_user=2
```

Scrapyd python API:

```
scrapyd.schedule(project,spider,request_user=2)
```

More information:

Schedule in Scrapyd JSON API: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule-json

Schedule in Scrapyd python API: https://python-scrapyd-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#schedule-a-job-to-run